# Expected number of distinct elements out of random selection

Tags: pr.probability

What is the expected number of distinct elements when choosing `N` random elements of a set of size `N`?

Comment: I've spent 4 hours on this problem using Mathematica and only came up with a slow numeric solution.

Comment: Check out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72223/finding-expected-number-of-distinct-values-selected-from-a-set-of-integers

Comment: Found an answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/expected-number-of-unique-items-when-drawing-with-replacement Thanks!